# C compiler not found in Dymola Python interface

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, dymola

I wrote a python script which runs some Modelica scripts file for Gitlab pipeline continuous integration. I could get the python script to work from command line without any issues, however, whenever I trigger the pipeline in Gitlab, I got errors below, I am curious if anyone encountered similar issues and could provide a solution possibly?

> No compiler selected. Please select a version of Visual C++ or GCC. For instructions on how to install a supported compiler, please visit www.dymola.com/compiler.

I tried to use `SetDymolaCompiler` method, but it still gives me the same error.
 (BTW, the documentation in the python interface was incorrect. In the documentation, string lists (see marco's answer and my correction) were used to set compiler location, however, I figured that it should be a map actually).

Here's the code I was running:

```
dymola_obj = None
try:
    dym_obj = DymolaInterface(dymola_exe)
    dym_obj.cd(mc_work_dir)
    dym_obj.SetDymolaCompiler("vs", {"CCompiler":"MSVC","MSVCDir":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Vc"})
    success = dym_obj.ExecuteCommand("some command")
except DymolaException as ex:
    success = False
finally:
    if dym_obj is not None:
        dym_obj.close()
        dym_obj = None
return success
```

- OS: Win 10 Pro (on a VM)
- Dymola: 2018 FD01

**Correction:**

Python interface documentation is still incorrect, in order to change compiler settings one should use [] instead of { }.

Python interface documentation:

```
SetDymolaCompiler("vs", {"CCompiler=MSVC","MSVCDir=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Vc"});
```

Should be changed to:

```
SetDymolaCompiler("vs", ["CCompiler=MSVC","MSVCDir=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Vc"]);
```

Comment: Regarding the python interface documentation: Only sections with the headline "Python example" refer to python. The other examples show how the commands can be executed inside Dymola using Modelica code. Often the Modelica examples can be used in the python interface as well, but not always (as in your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try with gitlab, but I found an error when running your code on my machine with Dymola 2018 FD01 and python 2.7.

In fact SetDymolaCompiler really does require a list of strings. You have to replace the line

```
 dym_obj.SetDymolaCompiler("vs", {"CCompiler":"MSVC","MSVCDir":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Vc"});
```

with

```
dym_obj.SetDymolaCompiler('vs', ['CCompiler=MSVC', 'MSVCDir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Vc'])
```

Some tips when working with the python interface:

- activate the Dymola window during development with 
   `DymolaInterface(showwindow=True)`
- set breakpoints and check after every command what Dymola writes to the command window. In your case it got obvious that `SetDymolaCompiler` was not executed due to syntax errors and the compiler was not set

And finally, your minimal example does not work, as python code lines must not end with ;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try. I admit adding_semi_colon = stupid; oops